# Loading an image from AWS S3 in Xamarin

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, xamarin, mobile, amazon-s3

I am trying to load a picture from an aws S3 storage, but nothing happens by running this code:

```
//AWS S3
var loggingConfig = AWSConfigs.LoggingConfig;
loggingConfig.LogMetrics = true;
loggingConfig.LogResponses = ResponseLoggingOption.Always;
loggingConfig.LogMetricsFormat = LogMetricsFormatOption.JSON;
loggingConfig.LogTo = LoggingOptions.SystemDiagnostics;
AWSConfigs.AWSRegion = "us-east-1";
AWSConfigsS3.UseSignatureVersion4 = true;

CognitoAWSCredentials mycredentials = 
    new CognitoAWSCredentials("eu-west-1:a1e69edc-7ee4-4c67-90de-4b7ae67efbb6", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(mycredentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);


TransferUtilityDownloadRequest downreq = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
downreq.FilePath = Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.ToString() + "Add.png";
downreq.BucketName = "crejopod";
downreq.Key = "Add.png";
CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken(true);
transferUtility.DownloadAsync(downreq, token);

//show the image
dayImage.Source = Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.ToString() + "Add.png";
```

Because I am using Version3 of the awssdk I have to use the DownloadAsync() function.

Comment: do NOT post code as images.  Please take the time to post and format the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: i have changed it. Thanks for telling me this - I am very new

Comment: you need to await the async method before you check its results

Comment: this helped, but now i am getting the error message:  Application Setting exception, Unable to store CognitiIdentity:IdentityId:eu-west1:a1....b6, got error Param.